# Расположение 2-х картинок на странице

Tags: html, вёрстка

Такое вопрос. Хочу расположить 2 картинки друг на друга, что б на нажатие на верхнюю она удалялась и оставалась только одна картинка.

```
<img style="width: 100%; height: 100%" src="Img/Simpsons/BartSkirt.jpg">

<img style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative; top: -100%;" src="Img/Simpsons/Homer.jpg">
```

Так вроде работает но есть 1 минус. Пространство под  фотками(где по идеи должна быть 2-ая фотка) пустое. Все тупо съезжает. Как это исправить?

Comment: Это должно быть на реализовано средствами HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А почему бы при нажатии, просто не менять атрибут src и не использовать одну картинку?

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var urls = [
    'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-A58yPmvdnIc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2o1tCSQHEG0/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
    'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DBNBnMLsnrs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/onFqjfb9JQs/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
    'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8f/cc/53/8fcc536c373eea4264d20a01f29341b5--homer-simpson-donuts-simpsons-donut.jpg',
    'http://www.drawingstep.com/images/smmaggie.jpg'
  ];
  var idx = 0;
  $('#img').click(function() {
    if (idx < urls.length)
      this.src = urls[idx++];
  }).click();
});
```

```css
#img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img" />
```

Или на чистом JS

```js
var urls = [
  'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-A58yPmvdnIc/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/2o1tCSQHEG0/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
  'https://yt3.ggpht.com/-DBNBnMLsnrs/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/onFqjfb9JQs/s100-c-k-no-mo-rj-c0xffffff/photo.jpg',
  'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/8f/cc/53/8fcc536c373eea4264d20a01f29341b5--homer-simpson-donuts-simpsons-donut.jpg',
  'http://www.drawingstep.com/images/smmaggie.jpg'
];
var idx = 0;

function imgClick(AImg) {
  if (idx < urls.length)
    AImg.src = urls[idx++];
}
```

```css
#img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="imgClick(document.getElementById('img'))">
  <img id="img" onclick="imgClick(this)" />
</body>
```

Comment: спасибо, хорошая идея, но только мне нужно все на чистом js

Comment: @ПавелЮхневич Переписал на чистый JS